# Django Rest testing status code with pytest

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm trying to test the status code of a project DRF.

```py
def test_status_code(client):
    resp = client.get('/myapi/api/')
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

I expect the output 200, but the actual is 401.

With comments received, I tried to do this:

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

@pytest.fixture
def user():
    token = Token.objects.get(user__username='foo')
    client = APIClient()
    user = client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token' + token.key)
    return user


def test_view_status_code(client, user):
    resp = client.get('/myapi/api/')
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Because your service has an authentication?

Comment: What parameters I need to pass the user and password?

Comment: It depends on your REST API. What authentication protocol did you use?

Comment: Basic  authentication (-a)...

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs

Comment: Thank you for reference. I tried to write a fixture...

Comment: What you have is the token authentication. Basic authentication is passed via header `Authorization: Basic <secret>`, where `<secret>` is username and password, separated by colon and base64-encoded. `plain = username + ':' + password; secret = base64.b64encode(plain.encode()).decode(); client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Basic ' + secret)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `login()` method on the client first:

```
def test_view_status_code(client, user):
    username = 'foo'
    password = 'bar'
    user.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
    client.login(username=username, password=password)
    response = client.get('/myapi/api/')
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```